# Xcode 5 won't even open in OS X 10.8.5

Tags: xcode, macos, ios7, osx-mountain-lion, xcode5

I recently updated my Mac OS to 10.8.5 and installed Xcode 5. First couple of times it opened but it was excruciatingly slow. Actions like cleaning, building the project took ages and when it finally ran, even the app won't function properly. It was like the app was frozen. So I quit Xcode to re-open it but now even Xcode won't start. I had to force quit every time I tried to open it.

I removed Xcode and installed it twice. One time from the .dmg I downloaded separately and the other time, through the Mac App store. But both time the same not responding issue persisted.

Can anyone please tell me how to rectify this issue? I'd really appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like a hard drive problem; but without more information it's just a guess

Comment: Anything in the system logs (use `Console.app`)?

Comment: I reinstalled Mountain Lion (been wanting to format my Mac anyway) and installed Xcode 5. Now it works fine.